# update database with migration after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, migration

I am developing web API in ASP.NET Core. I am looking for a way for Update customer's database with publish API Files [Automatically].
I don't want to use update-database
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all you need is to call `context.Database.Migrate()` on application start. I have recently ran into this implementation of `IWebHost` extension which allows to migrate database context on startup and run a custom action to seed the database with some default data.

```cs
public static class IWebHostExtensions
{
    public static IWebHost MigrateDbContext<TContext>(this IWebHost webHost, Action<TContext, IServiceProvider> seeder)
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TContext>>();

            var context = services.GetService<TContext>();

            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Migrating database associated with context {typeof(TContext).Name}");

                context.Database.Migrate();

                seeder(context, services);

                logger.LogInformation($"Migrated database associated with context {typeof(TContext).Name}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred while migrating the database used on context {typeof(TContext).Name}");
            }
        }

        return webHost;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args)
            .MigrateDbContext<MyDbContext>((context, services) =>
            {
                var configuration = services.GetService<IConfiguration>();

                MyDbContext.SeedAsync(context).Wait();
            })
            .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After executing the project, the update command will run automatically